# Не добавляются данные в таблицу Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой код

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    include 'database.php';



    function  CheckElement($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = stripcslashes($data);
        $data = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn , $data);
        return $data;
    }   



    $name = CheckElement($_POST['authname']);
    $pass = CheckElement($_POST['authpassword']);
    $passagain = CheckElement($_POST['authpasswordagain']);
    $email = CheckElement($_POST['authemail']);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name , user_password , user_password2 , user_email) VALUES 
    ('".$name."' , '".$pass."' , '".$passagain."' , '".$email."' )";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

   if ($query) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
   }


  }


?>



 <form action="<?php print htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" class="form" method="POST"   onsubmit="return CheckFunction()"  name="register">
            <label for="auth">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="authname" placeholder="Enter Name" id="auth"><span id="errorname"></span>
            <label for="auth">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="authpassword" placeholder="Enter Password" id="auth"><span id="errorpass"></span>
            <label for="auth">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="authpasswordagain" placeholder="Enter Password Again" id="auth"><span id="errorpass2"></span>
            <label for="auth">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="authemail" placeholder="Enter Email" id="auth"><span id="erroremail"></span>
            <button type="submit">Button</button>
        </form>
```

Не добавляются данные в таблицу. Помогите разобратся.Заранне Спасибо

Comment: Ошибки какие-то выводит?

Comment: нет никаких ошибок

Comment: используйте ООП и всем нам станет проще, проверьте 1. что у вас после отправки формы код заходит в условие if (isset($_POST['register'])) 2. проверьте сам запрос попробуйте выполнить его на клиенте 3. откуда у вас в глобальной функции CheckElement() переменная $conn? 4. используйте try { } catch (\Throwable $e) {}

Comment: Cпасибо  за  совет  . Побробую

Comment: При смене с местами `<form name="register"></form> `  на  `<button name="register"></button>`  код срабатывает но  добовляется ошыбка про    `mysqli_real_esacape_string() `

Comment: Можете подсказать  разницу??

Comment: Разница в том, что атрибут `name` у `<form>` никак не обрабатывается в PHP. То есть в предыдущем случае условие `if (isset($_POST['register']))` у вас просто не срабатывало. Атрибут `name` у `<button>` уже передается в POST-запросе и условие срабатывает. Ошибка `mysqli_real_esacape_string()` потому что внутри функции `CheckElement()` не определена переменная `$conn`. Просто передавайте туда подключение к БД -
`function  CheckElement($data, $conn)
{`
или определите внутри функции, что `$conn` это глобальная переменная -
`function  CheckElement($data)
{
    global $conn;
    .....`

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решился вот таким образом

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    include 'database.php';



    function  CheckElement($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = stripcslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }   



    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn ,CheckElement($_POST['authname']));
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn ,CheckElement($_POST['authpassword']));
    $passagain = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn ,  CheckElement($_POST['authpasswordagain']));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , CheckElement($_POST['authemail']));



    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name , user_password , user_password2 , user_email) VALUES 
    ('".$name."' , '".$pass."' , '".$passagain."' , '".$email."' )";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

   if ($query) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
   }


  }




 ?>

<form action="<?php print htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" class="form" method="POST"   onsubmit="return CheckFunction()">
            <label for="auth">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="authname" placeholder="Enter Name" id="auth"><span id="errorname"></span>
            <label for="auth">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="authpassword" placeholder="Enter Password" id="auth"><span id="errorpass"></span>
            <label for="auth">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="authpasswordagain" placeholder="Enter Password Again" id="auth"><span id="errorpass2"></span>
            <label for="auth">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="authemail" placeholder="Enter Email" id="auth"><span id="erroremail"></span>
            <button type="submit"  name="register">Button</button>
        </form>
```

Спасибо всем за совет